# How to make the subfigures appear visible with less vertical space between side-by-side subfigures and be consistent with the same size?

Tags: captions, subfloats

Currently, I am using a this code to generate the subfigures as one figure.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[textfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{float} 
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{BISb2.png}
\caption{$S_b$ in BI}
\label{fig:BIa}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{HSISb.png}
\caption{$S_b$ in HSI}
\label{fig:HSIa}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{BIIb2.png}%, height=0.15\textheight
\caption{$I_b$ in BI}
\label{fig:BIb}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{HSIIb.png}
\caption{$I_b$ in HSI}
\label{fig:HSIb}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{BISh.png}
\caption{$S_h$ in BI}
\label{fig:BIc}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{HSISh.png}
\caption{$S_h$ in HSI}
\label{fig:HSIc}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{BIIa.png}
\caption{$I_a$ in BI}
\label{fig:BId}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{HSIIa.png}
\caption{$I_a$ in HSI}
\label{fig:HSId}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{BIRh.png}
\caption{$R_h$ in BI}
\label{fig:BIe}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{HSIRh.png}
\caption{$R_h$ in HSI}
\label{fig:HSIe}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{\small{The figures on the left column represent the state trajectories of the BI (bilinear incidence) models and the figures on the right column correspond to that of HSI (half-saturated incidence) models. The parameter values and initial conditions that are used in both models are listed i Table~\ref{tab:table2}. Observe that the endemic equilibrium point ($E_{AH}^* = (S_b^*, I_b^*, S_h^*, I_a^*, R_h^*) = (1.3950, 1166.4224, 280706.4850, 0.1329, 1342.5412)$) is consistent to the steady state values of $S_b, I_b, S_h, I_a$, and  $R_h$ shown in the left column.}}
\label{fig:BItrajectory}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and the following output looks like this.
[image: example output]

The current issues are

- the caption of the figure was not able to show every information.
- subfigures aren't visible to see
- I want to make the subfigures be consistent with the same size (height and width)

Is there a way or specific code to fix these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to restrict the heights of the 10 graphs. Be sure to specify the option `keepaspectratio` to make sure that distortion is avoided.

Code along the lines shown in the following example may be helpful. (Be sure to remove the `demo` option in your real document.)

A separate comment: Don't confuse or mix up the legend and the caption. The latter should generally be short and snappy, to inform the reader at a glance what the `figure` is all about. The legend can (and should) be as long as is necessary to explain in depth what the reader should be taking away from perusing the graphs.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters appropriately
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{font={bf,small},skip=0.25\baselineskip}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p]
\begin{subfigure}{0.475\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,
    height=0.13\textheight,keepaspectratio]{BISb2.png}
\caption{$S_b$ in BI}
\label{fig:BIa}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.475\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,
    height=0.13\textheight,keepaspectratio]{HSISb.png}
\caption{$S_b$ in HSI}
\label{fig:HSIa}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.475\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,
    height=0.13\textheight,keepaspectratio]{BIIb2.png}
\caption{$I_b$ in BI}
\label{fig:BIb}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.475\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,
    height=0.13\textheight,keepaspectratio]{HSIIb.png}
\caption{$I_b$ in HSI}
\label{fig:HSIb}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.475\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,
    height=0.13\textheight,keepaspectratio]{BISh.png}
\caption{$S_h$ in BI}
\label{fig:BIc}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.475\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,
    height=0.13\textheight,keepaspectratio]{HSISh.png}
\caption{$S_h$ in HSI}
\label{fig:HSIc}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.475\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,
    height=0.13\textheight,keepaspectratio]{BIIa.png}
\caption{$I_a$ in BI}
\label{fig:BId}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.475\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,
    height=0.13\textheight,keepaspectratio]{HSIIa.png}
\caption{$I_a$ in HSI}
\label{fig:HSId}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.475\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,
    height=0.13\textheight,keepaspectratio]{BIRh.png}
\caption{$R_h$ in BI}
\label{fig:BIe}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.475\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,
    height=0.13\textheight,keepaspectratio]{HSIRh.png}
\caption{$R_h$ in HSI}
\label{fig:HSIe}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip\footnotesize
The figures in the left-hand column represent the state trajectories of the BI (bilinear incidence) models, and the figures in the right-hand column correspond to that of HSI (half-saturated incidence) models. The parameter values and initial conditions that are used in both models are listed in Table~\ref{tab:table2}. Observe that the endemic equilibrium point ($E_{AH}^* = (S_b^*, I_b^*, S_h^*, I_a^*, R_h^*) = (1.3950, 1166.4224, 280706.4850, 0.1329, 1342.5412)$) is consistent with the steady state values of $S_b$, $I_b$, $S_h$, $I_a$, and  $R_h$ shown in the left-hand column.
\caption{Ten graphs with legend} % keep caption short and snappy
\label{fig:BItrajectory}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, the subfigures are now clear and less distorted. But the vertical space between the side-by-side subfigures is still big. For example, I want the space between Figure1(a) and Figure1(b) to be small as possible. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @massmatics -  you could change the 5 `\hfill` instructions to `\quad`.

Comment: I tried \quad but it didn't reduce the white vertical space that much.
Also, my footnotes were aligned at center for some reason... I want my footnotes before the Figure caption to be aligned like a paragraph form. Is there another code that can fix these issues?

Comment: @massmatics - Sorry, I had misread "vertical" for "horizontal" in  your earlier comment; indeed, changing `\hfill` to `\quad` doesn't change the vertical spacing! Sorry for that. To minimize the space between the subfigures and their captions, run the instruction (in the preamble) `\captionsetup[subfigure]{font={bf,small}, skip=1pt}`. If the legend material is center-set, it's probably because you have a `\centering` instruction somewhere. (Note that the code in my answer deliberateley did away with all `\centering` directives.)

Comment: Yes but how do I minimize the vertical space between side-by-side figures?